# Whonix/Tor Bug/Error

Tags: whonix, time

Whenever I try to run the Whonix Network Time Syncing from the Workstation I keep getting the following error message:

[image: You can only see the image, when you are logged into stackexchange.]

However whenever I run Network Time Syncing in Gateway, It will sit at about 10% in the status bar and wont move, even after leaving it for almost an hour.

I have my System clock set to exactly the same as the Whonix internal clock (UTC time) But I still cant connect through the Tor Browser.

Any Ideas?

Comment: Not specific to Tor. Moderator, can you migrate this one to unix.se please?

Comment: Did you [verify](https://www.whonix.org/wiki/Download#Verify_the_Whonix_images) your Whonix [download](https://www.whonix.org/wiki/Download)?

Comment: @adrelanos The easiest and most reliable way to get our attention is to flag the question, choosing the most appropriate options. :) That said, I think that it's perfectly fine here - as your answer shows, the exact cause could well be related to Tor. I'll happily revisit this when Keno13 provides the information you requested.

Comment: @adrelanos
The PGP key adrelanos.asc was fine. However when I tried to verify the the Workstation and Gateway Keys it came up with an error message along the lines of "no key found". Id get you exactly what it said but KGPG wont open for some reason... This morning I changed my clock back to where I am located. I ran Whonix Check and Time Sync from Gate Way and this time they both worked fine. However when I went to do it in Workstation It came up with the same error message again for Whonix Check (The one screen shot I originally posted) and the Time Sync still sat on 10% again. The Time Sync

Comment: This is not a discussion forum. Please do not use the answer function unless you are answering the question. `The PGP key adrelanos.asc was fine. However when I tried to verify the the Workstation and Gateway. Keys it came up with an error message along the lines of "no key found".` - This is the first thing you need to sort out. Other error might result from this. `I have been using Tor for months on a Windows Platform.` Now you are using an Ubuntu host. Windows isn't Ubuntu. The first other thing you'd need to learn first is to get original TBB working on your Ubuntu host.

Comment: It looks like you have lost access to your unregistered account http://tor.stackexchange.com/users/558/keno13. You should be able to regain the control by using the [Account Recovery](http://tor.stackexchange.com/users/account-recovery) function according to [I lost control of my account before registering. Is it lost forever?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/95358/220244) --- You can also ask for the two accounts to be merged: [I accidentally created two accounts; how do I merge them?](http://tor.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts)

Comment: I noticed that you have probably control over the first account. The information in this post belongs to the original question. Please edit it. This post will be removed because it is not an answer to your question.

Answer (score 1):

> However whenever I run Network Time Syncing in Gateway, It will sit at about 10% in the status bar and wont move, even after leaving it for almost an hour.

What does `whonixcheck` say?

What does sdwdate's log say?

To find that out, run.

```
tail -f /var/log/sdwdate.log
```

Add this information using the comment function and I will update this answer.

> I have my System clock set to exactly the same as the Whonix internal clock (UTC time)

This is wrong. And you shouldn't try such things without being told so in documentation or without knowing what you are doing. Leave your host's (the host is the system you were using without knowing about Whonix) system clock to what it is usually set, i.e. your usual time zone and your current time.

I think it's likely, that Tor isn't able to connect in the first place. Running `whonixcheck` on Whonix-Gateway will tell. Are you living in a censored area (rhetoric question)? Have you followed the [recommendation](https://www.whonix.org/wiki/Pre_Install_Advice#Tor_Browser_Bundle) to learn how to use the Tor Browser Bundle on your host first? Does that work for you?