# Whonix cannot sync time

Tags: configuration, whonix, network-configuration, torcheck

I am trying to sync the time on both whonix gateway and workstation but am getting the following connectivity errors upon running whonixcheck with the verbose flag set. On the gateway I get:

```
$ whonixcheck --verbose
```

[image: whonix check 1]

[image: whonix check 2]

Next, when running arm on the gateway there seems to be no connection to the tor network:

[image: whonix arm]

Following the steps suggested in the answer of [this](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/809/whonix-tor-bug-error) question the log files are:

```
tail -f /var/log/sdwdate.log
```

[image: sdwupdate]

When running **timesync** on the gateway I get:

[image: timesync 1]
[image: timesync 2]
[image: timesync 3]
[image: timesync 4]

When running:

```
tail -f -n 20 /var/log/sdwdate.log
```

The following are shown:

[image: timesync 5]

What is weird is that I cannot set the **hwclock**.

Setting the time by running:

```
# date +%T -s "01:01:30"
```

is reset after a reboot (I'm running whonix in VirtualBox on a Win7 host machine).

After, the time update the **hwclock** gives the same output as prior to setting the time.

I'm not sure how relevant this is, but a few days ago I made a dual boot setup (debian/win7) and booted in debian. I also disabled the UEFI boot option in BIOS in order to be able to boot from a USB stick and install debian.

Why isn't whonix able to sync its time?

Comment: https://forums.whonix.org/t/whonix-is-unable-to-synchronize-time